# how to solve this PDE? Can I emplement method of separating variables?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

how to solve this PDE? I am solving advanced engineering math. I have the expression.
$$\begin{align}
   u_{xx} - u_{yy} - u_x - u_y &= 0
\\ u(x,0) &= 0
\\ u(x,x) &= x
\\ u_y(x,0) & =e^{x/2}
\end{align}$$

How do I get $u(x,y)$? I thought I have to use the d'Alambert method.. but this method is not working because $u(x,0)=0$... Or, Can I emplement method of separating variables? then How can I Use this method?

Comment: Separation of variables works incredible well on this specific question. Give it a try, if you get stuck I'll post an answer later.

Comment: u = F(x)G(y), F''G-FG''=F'G+FG', F''-F'-kF=0, G''+G'-kG=0 ..I've tried this. Is this right?
And then what to do..

Comment: Why not trie it out yourself?

Comment: I've just learned PDE and tried how to learn it here. I looked for other books or problems, but I didn't see a similar type.  I don't think I have a clue. I'm sorry if I didn't seem to do it myself. The above comment is because I was confused whether the way I do it is a variable separation method.

Comment: @mouin please include your attempt in the original question. The next step is to solve the two ODEs.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\xi=x-y$ and $\eta=x+y$; then, using the chain rule, we can rewrite the PDE as
$$
(\partial_{\xi}+\partial_{\eta})^2u-(-\partial_{\xi}+\partial_{\eta})^2u-(\partial_{\xi}+\partial_{\eta})u-(-\partial_{\xi}+\partial_{\eta})u=0 
$$
$$
\implies(4\partial_{\xi}\partial_{\eta}-2\partial_{\eta})u=0\implies 
\partial_{\eta}(2\partial_{\xi}-1)u=0. \tag{1}
$$
It's straightforward to show that the general solution to $(1)$ is
$$
u=f(\xi)+g(\eta)e^{\xi/2}=f(x-y)+g(x+y)e^{(x-y)/2}, \tag{2}
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary differentiable functions. To determine them, we use the conditions $u(x,0)=0$ and $u(x,x)=x$:
$$
u(x,0)=0 \implies f(x)+g(x)e^{x/2}=0 \implies f(x)=-g(x)e^{x/2}
$$
$$
\implies u(x,y)=[-g(x-y)+g(x+y)]e^{(x-y)/2}, \tag{3}
$$
$$
u(x,x)=x \implies -g(0)+g(2x)=x \implies g(x)=g(0)+\frac{x}{2}
$$
$$
\implies u(x,y)=ye^{(x-y)/2}. \quad \square \tag{4}
$$
One can easily verify that $(4)$ also satisfies the condition $u_y(x,0)=e^{x/2}$.